# C# Save byte array as xml file

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, arrays, byte

I'm receiving a `.zip` file from a server.

The `.zip` file is sent `64Base` encoded and it contains an XML file.

After I decode the data to binary using `Convert.FromBase64String`, can I convert the byte array to XML?

I don't want to deal with unzipping.

I tried the following code: (that resulted in Gibberish that doesn't make any sense and doesn't look like XML at all)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you don't want to unzip, but do you actually mean that you don't want to unzip to disc?  Most zip libraries either allow you to unzip a file to a byte array directly or to a stream where you could pass it a MemoryStream.

There's no getting around having to uncompress.  Unless you have control over the server side, then you could change the format to an uncompressed file (like a tar file).  Then you wouldn't have to uncompress.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I'm receiving a .zip file from a server.

And:

> I don't want to deal with unzipping.

Well. You have to. If the data is in a `zip` archive, you need to extract it first. You can't just ignore the fact.

There are plenty of `zip` libraries - [sharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) is free and easy enough to use.

Comment: @Sash - No problem. Since it deals with `Stream`s, you can use `MemoryStream` to manage decompression directly in memory.